# How can I solve my Close/Dispose Unhandled Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm developing a Windows Forms App, a connector between a callCenter and a CRM and I'm clogged with an unhandled exception which I can't understand or either solve.

My App has:

- MainForm with some controls and a FlowControll Pannel which may or may not show a collection of SearchForms - OK
- SearchForm - basically a DataGridView with clickable cells - depending on the column index, the click will perform different operations - OK
- DialForm - loads as consequence of clicking a cell on my SearchForm and allows to i) Cancel (closes the form OK); ii) dial a number  -PROBLEM - very frustrating

When I click to dial, the app correctly makes the phoneCall trough my callCenter, but the very next line of code (Dispose() upon the DialForm) generates an unhandled exception of type 'Safe Handle has been closed', reportedly with DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success).

The relevant methods:

```
///
/// DialForm Method - upon clicking «Dial Number» Button
///
private void dialButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
    // Piece of code to manage closing with DialFormCloseEventArgs
    //
    DialFormCloseEventArgs args = new DialFormCloseEventArgs();
    args.toClose = this;
    EventHandler<DialFormCloseEventArgs> eh = father.Search_CloseDialForm;
    this.BeginInvoke(eh, new object[] { sender, args });
}

///
/// SearchForm Method - EventHandler to close DialForm and make call
///
public void Search_CloseDialForm(object sender, DialFormCloseEventArgs e)
{
    string numberToDial = e.toClose.numberToDial.Text;
    e.toClose.Dispose();
    this.rePositionMainForm();
    using (ConectorCTI.ConectorCTI ctiws = new ConectorCTI.ConectorCTI())
    {
        ctiws.Timeout = 180000;

        // Synchronous Call
        //ctiws.Dial(this.userLoginName, numberToDial, "");

        // Assynchronous Call
        ctiws.DialAsync(this.userLoginName, numberToDial, "");
    }
}
```

[I also show my App with textual descriptions so you can actually «see it»](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbchd.png)
[image]

Comment: The Seach_CloseDialForm event handler returns to the form that you dispose. What could happen then is not predictable.

Comment: At least try to debug before posting

Comment: `e.toClose.Dispose();` you are clearly disposing your form.  I'm with @CamiloTerevinto, did you try debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably need to wait for the async task to complete before disposing of the object.  Something like

```
using (ConectorCTI.ConectorCTI ctiws = new ConectorCTI.ConectorCTI())
{
    var task = ctiws.DialAsync(this.userLoginName, numberToDial, "");
    await task;
}
```

Comment: Why create the variable task at all?